# How to connect a pretty old hard drive to MacMini?

Tags: hard-drive, mac-mini

I have a rather old iOmega external hard drive which I'd like to connect to a quite new Mac, but I always get confused by Apple plugs so I have no idea what type of cable do I need.

These are the connectivity options for the hard drive:
[image]

and these are for the Mac:
[image]

Any ideas what type of cable do I need for connecting these two?

Comment: Can you please specify the model of the hard drive you are using?

Comment: @DManokhin That no is not needed the pictures of the connectors is sufficient

Comment: @Mark the picture shows 2 x Firewire 800 connectors, 1 x USB B and 3 x USB A. Are you sure this drive can be mounted via USB, or could the USB connectors just be for a USB hub which is separate from the drive? That's why the model would help.

Answer (score 2):

You need an USB B to A cable.

USB B is the type of connector that fits your hard drive. 
USB A is what you'd call "classic USB" and that fits your Mac.

[image]

Alternatively you can use an Thunderbolt-to-Firewire adapter and then a Firewire cable. This might offer higher speeds. But it's also the more expensive option.

Comment: Personally, I'd go with the Thunderbolt to Firewire over USB any day. Apple [has a dongle available](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD464LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-to-firewire-adapter). Short (6") firewire cables [here](https://www.usbfirewire.com/parts/rr-cfb-9902-09.html#RR-9S9S-06G).

Comment: There is a really good chance that you have a printer somewhere that came with this cable, as it is quire common with USB printers. (but agree, Firewire will be far faster than the old drive's USB 2.0)

Comment: The USB part might purely be for the hub part and not the HDD?

Comment: @JohnKeates can you please tell me what the 'hub' refers to? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: This is probably an Iomega MiniMax. This device can connect through USB as well (if I read the specs correctly).